# google calendar api with easyappointments

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

hello please help me regarding google calendar api with easyappointments system

my code is:-

```
const GOOGLE_SYNC_FEATURE   = TRUE; // Enter TRUE or FALSE
const GOOGLE_PRODUCT_NAME   = 'mybooking';
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID      = '***************************.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET  = '***************************';
const GOOGLE_API_KEY        = 'AIzaSyACWSs_***************************';
```

Authorized redirect URIs

http://dev.dissertationconsulting.co.uk/bookingsystem/workjoy/bookings/index.php/google/oauth_callback

when i enable sync i have error on my page

Error: invalid_request

400. That’s an error.

Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme:

url of easyappointments:

http://easyappointments.org/

please suggest me something what should i try to enable google calender
with easyappointments.

Comment: Do not share your private keys to public

Comment: While we have edited out your private key, it still appears in the history. Please delete and create a new one.